# Problem in running Flutter first counter app on vscode

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code, keystore

I just downloaded flutter sdk and tried to launch flutter first app on vscode it is showing this error. Please help me to resolve this error. I just started learning flutter i dont know much about flutter.

```
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\ADMIN\.android\debug.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

Comment: looks like your default (android) debug keystore (`debug.keystore`) might be messed up.

Comment: [a very useful link to read](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) - try checking your keystore and it's fingerprint, whether it's good and works or not.

Answer (score 0):

in terminal run

```
flutter doctor
```

to check if you have android SDK setup correctly

Answer (score 0):

I was already using gradle 6.3.
If your not using gradle 6.3.. then go to gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper. properties and change the distribution Url to this

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

If you still get that error.. follow these steps:

1. Delete .gradle folder from android folder.

The above steps fixed the problem.

Comment: but i an working on flutter and i think this for react-native

Comment: No, this is a Flutter App method only. Go to > android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and replace distributionUrl to this distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip